# Windows Bitmap encoder only writing bottom few thousand pixels

Tags: c++, windows

The `ReadBmpFromFile/Stream` functions work fine. (Still a little slow but they otherwise work). The `WriteBmpToFile/Stream` functions work in that they successfully create a valid `.bmp` file but only the bottom few thousands of pixels, the rest of the file is black.

It shouldn't be that hard to see why, the pixel data is stored from bottom to top so the problem should be near the top of the file.

Reference: [BMP File structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#File_structure)

Original:

[image: Sprite sheet original to be read from]

Copy:

[image: Copy of original written to a different filename]

I stepped through with a debugger and the data is successfully being copied from the containing object. It shouldn't fail when I am reading from a file and then immediately writing it back:

```
if(_keyboard->KeyDown(KEY_S)) {
    BitmapFileType bmp_test;
    ReadBmpFromFile("maglot.bmp_test", bmp_test);

    //Change filename to not destroy original!
    WriteBmpToFile("maglot_copy.bmp_test", bmp_test);

    //Allegro's implementation to test correct output against.
    //save_bmp("maglot_copy.bmp", image->GetImage(), nullptr);
}
```

Bitmap class definition:

```
class BitmapFileType {
public:
    struct Header {
        std::vector<unsigned char> file_signature;
        unsigned int file_size;
        unsigned short unused1;
        unsigned short unused2;
        unsigned int pixel_array_offset;
        unsigned int DIB_header_size;
        unsigned int width;
        unsigned int height;
        unsigned short plane_count;
        unsigned short bpp;

        unsigned int compression_method;
        unsigned int raw_size;
        unsigned int print_resolution_horizontal;
        unsigned int print_resolution_vertical;
        unsigned int pallete_colors_count;
        unsigned int important_colors_count;

        Header() :
            file_signature(2),
            file_size(0),
            unused1(0),
            unused2(0),
            pixel_array_offset(0),
            DIB_header_size(0),
            width(0),
            height(0),
            plane_count(0),
            bpp(0),
            compression_method(0),
            raw_size(0),
            print_resolution_horizontal(0),
            print_resolution_vertical(0),
            pallete_colors_count(0),
            important_colors_count(0)
        { /* DO NOTHING */ }

        Header(const Header& other) :
        file_signature(other.file_signature),
            file_size(other.file_size),
            unused1(other.unused1),
            unused2(other.unused2),
            pixel_array_offset(other.pixel_array_offset),
            DIB_header_size(other.DIB_header_size),
            width(other.width),
            height(other.height),
            plane_count(other.plane_count),
            bpp(other.bpp),
            compression_method(other.compression_method),
            raw_size(other.raw_size),
            print_resolution_horizontal(other.print_resolution_horizontal),
            print_resolution_vertical(other.print_resolution_vertical),
            pallete_colors_count(other.pallete_colors_count),
            important_colors_count(other.important_colors_count)
        { /* DO NOTHING */ }

        Header& operator=(const Header& rhs) {
            if(this == &rhs) return *this;

            this->file_signature = rhs.file_signature;
            this->file_size = rhs.file_size;
            this->unused1 = rhs.unused1;
            this->unused2 = rhs.unused2;
            this->pixel_array_offset = rhs.pixel_array_offset;
            this->DIB_header_size = rhs.DIB_header_size;
            this->width = rhs.width;
            this->height = rhs.height;
            this->plane_count = rhs.plane_count;
            this->bpp = rhs.bpp;
            this->compression_method = rhs.compression_method;
            this->raw_size = rhs.raw_size;
            this->print_resolution_horizontal = rhs.print_resolution_horizontal;
            this->print_resolution_vertical = rhs.print_resolution_vertical;
            this->pallete_colors_count = rhs.pallete_colors_count;
            this->important_colors_count = rhs.important_colors_count;

            return *this;
        }

    };
    struct PixelData {
        std::vector<unsigned char> _pixel_data;
        PixelData() : _pixel_data() { /* DO NOTHING */ }
        PixelData(const PixelData& other) : _pixel_data(other._pixel_data) { /* DO NOTHING */ }
        PixelData(const std::vector<unsigned char>& pixel_data) : _pixel_data(pixel_data) { /* DO NOTHING */ }
    };

    BitmapFileType() : _header(), _data() { /* DO NOTHING */ }
    BitmapFileType(const BitmapFileType::Header& header) : _header(header), _data() { /* DO NOTHING */ }
    BitmapFileType(const BitmapFileType::Header& header, const PixelData& data) : _header(header), _data(data) { /* DO NOTHING */ }
    BitmapFileType& operator=(const BitmapFileType& rhs) {
        if(this == &rhs) return *this;

        _header = rhs._header;
        _data = rhs._data;

        return *this;
    }

    const Header& GetHeader() const {
        return _header;
    }

    Header& GetHeader() {
        return const_cast<Header&>(static_cast<const BitmapFileType&>(*this).GetHeader());
    }

    const PixelData& GetPixelData() const {
        return _data;
    }

    PixelData& GetPixelData() {
        return const_cast<PixelData&>(static_cast<const BitmapFileType&>(*this).GetPixelData());
    }

protected:
private:
    Header _header;
    PixelData _data;

};
```

Function definitions:

```
#include "FileTypeUtility.h"

#include <fstream>

void WriteBmpToFile(const std::string& filename, const BitmapFileType& bmp) {
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open(filename);
    WriteBmpToStream(ofs, bmp);
    ofs.close();
}

void ReadBmpFromFile(const std::string& filename, BitmapFileType& bmp) {
    std::ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open(filename);
    ReadBmpFromStream(ifs, bmp);
    ifs.close();
}

void ReadBmpFromStream(std::istream& input_stream, BitmapFileType& bmp) {

    if(input_stream.fail() || input_stream.bad() || input_stream.eof()) return;

    std::vector<unsigned char> file_signature(2);
    input_stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(file_signature.data()), file_signature.size());
    if((file_signature[0] != 'B' || file_signature[1] != 'M')) {
        input_stream.seekg(-2, std::ios_base::cur);
        input_stream.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        return;
    }

    unsigned int file_size = 0;
    input_stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&file_size), sizeof(file_size));

    unsigned short unused1 = 0;
    input_stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&unused1), sizeof(unused1));

    unsigned short unused2 = 0;
    input_stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&unused2), sizeof(unused2));

    unsigned int pixel_array_offset = 0;
    input_stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&pixel_array_offset), sizeof(pixel_array_offset));

    unsigned int DIB_header_size = 0;
    input_stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&DIB_header_size), sizeof(DIB_header_size));

    unsigned int width = 0;
    input_stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&width), sizeof(width));

    unsigned int height = 0;
    input_stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&height), sizeof(height));

    unsigned short plane_count = 0;
    input_stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&plane_count), sizeof(plane_count));

    unsigned short bpp = 0;
    input_stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&bpp), sizeof(bpp));

    unsigned int compression_method = 0;
    input_stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&compression_method), sizeof(compression_method));

    unsigned int raw_size = 0;
    input_stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&raw_size), sizeof(raw_size));

    unsigned int print_resolution_horizontal = 0;
    input_stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&print_resolution_horizontal), sizeof(print_resolution_horizontal));

    unsigned int print_resolution_vertical = 0;
    input_stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&print_resolution_vertical), sizeof(print_resolution_vertical));

    unsigned int pallete_colors_count = 0;
    input_stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&pallete_colors_count), sizeof(pallete_colors_count));

    unsigned int important_colors_count = 0;
    input_stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&important_colors_count), sizeof(important_colors_count));

    std::vector<unsigned char> pixel_array(raw_size);
    input_stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(pixel_array.data()), pixel_array.size());

    BitmapFileType::PixelData bmpPixels(pixel_array);

    BitmapFileType::Header bmpHeader;
    bmpHeader.file_signature = file_signature;
    bmpHeader.file_size = file_size;
    bmpHeader.unused1 = unused1;
    bmpHeader.unused2 = unused2;
    bmpHeader.pixel_array_offset = pixel_array_offset;
    bmpHeader.DIB_header_size = DIB_header_size;
    bmpHeader.width = width;
    bmpHeader.height = height;
    bmpHeader.plane_count = plane_count;
    bmpHeader.bpp = bpp;
    bmpHeader.compression_method = compression_method;
    bmpHeader.raw_size = raw_size;
    bmpHeader.print_resolution_horizontal = print_resolution_horizontal;
    bmpHeader.print_resolution_vertical = print_resolution_vertical;
    bmpHeader.pallete_colors_count = pallete_colors_count;
    bmpHeader.important_colors_count = important_colors_count;

    bmp = BitmapFileType(bmpHeader, bmpPixels);

    return;
}

void WriteBmpToStream(std::ostream& output_stream, const BitmapFileType& bmp) {

    if(output_stream.fail() || output_stream.bad() || output_stream.eof()) return;

    const BitmapFileType::Header& bmpHeader(bmp.GetHeader());

    output_stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(bmpHeader.file_signature.data()), bmpHeader.file_signature.size());

    output_stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&bmpHeader.file_size), sizeof(bmpHeader.file_size));

    output_stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&bmpHeader.unused1), sizeof(bmpHeader.unused1));
    output_stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&bmpHeader.unused2), sizeof(bmpHeader.unused2));

    output_stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&bmpHeader.pixel_array_offset), sizeof(bmpHeader.pixel_array_offset));
    output_stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&bmpHeader.DIB_header_size), sizeof(bmpHeader.DIB_header_size));

    output_stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&bmpHeader.width), sizeof(bmpHeader.width));
    output_stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&bmpHeader.height), sizeof(bmpHeader.height));

    output_stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&bmpHeader.plane_count), sizeof(bmpHeader.plane_count));
    output_stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&bmpHeader.bpp), sizeof(bmpHeader.bpp));

    output_stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&bmpHeader.compression_method), sizeof(bmpHeader.compression_method));
    output_stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&bmpHeader.raw_size), sizeof(bmpHeader.raw_size));
    output_stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&bmpHeader.print_resolution_horizontal), sizeof(bmpHeader.print_resolution_horizontal));
    output_stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&bmpHeader.print_resolution_vertical), sizeof(bmpHeader.print_resolution_vertical));
    output_stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&bmpHeader.pallete_colors_count), sizeof(bmpHeader.pallete_colors_count));
    output_stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&bmpHeader.important_colors_count), sizeof(bmpHeader.important_colors_count));

    const BitmapFileType::PixelData& bmpPixelData(bmp.GetPixelData());

    output_stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(bmpPixelData._pixel_data.data()), bmpPixelData._pixel_data.size());

    return;
}
```

Comment: Um, you didn't open the file for writing in binary mode. The default is text mode.

Comment: When you read it in, does the whole image get read in, or only part of it? Is the output file the correct size?

Comment: @RaymondChen Wow...total oversight. Now, how do I set the `istream` function version to binary?